# Trouble with using SMS manager when used with a Service

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am new to android. I am creating a android service which retrieves the current location and send it as a message to a particular number. I have almost achieved it, but when I use SMSManager to send message of the retrieved location value the app crashes(I have commented the code in the attachment). I have achieved up-to the step of retrieving the current location and display it on EditText. I have included all the permissions.Kindly help me to fix the issue of sending message of the received intent value. I have included the code of MainActivity and BroadcastService

```
int count=1;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                textView.setText("\n" +intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));

               String loc = textView.getText().toString();

                    /*
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage("7448958358", null, loc, null, null);
                    */

            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(broadcastReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "sending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if(!runtime_permissions())
    {
        enable_buttons();
    }
}

private void enable_buttons() {

    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BroadcastService.class);
            startService(i);
        }
    });

    btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BroadcastService.class);
            stopService(i);
        }
    });

}

private boolean runtime_permissions() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},100);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 100){
        if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            enable_buttons();
        }else {
            runtime_permissions();
        }
    }
}
```

*BroadcastService.java*

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Services has been started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            i.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //noinspection MissingPermission
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationManager != null){
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
}
```

My crash log says

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.prakaash.broadcastservice, PID: 27810
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=location_update flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.prakaash.broadcastservice.MainActivity$1@9f66542
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_51117(LoadedApk.java:1300)
                  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0(Unknown Source:4)
                  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10119 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
                  at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:867)
                  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:330)
                  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:313)
                  at com.example.prakaash.broadcastservice.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:42)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_51117(LoadedApk.java:1290)
                  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0(Unknown Source:4) 
                  at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: Can you update your question with crash log?

Comment: I have updated it.This is working perfectly in emulator but crashes only on mobile. On seeing logcat,only thing I understand is,"It is asking to include PHONE_STATE permission". Is it required for getting current location and sending it as a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue doesn't happen for all the manufacturers. The official document doesnt specify the need for requesting this permission. Some manufacturers have issues in implementation of  `sendTextMessage` due to which `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission is required.

To fix the issue only workaround is to add this permission to your Manifest and `requestPermissions`.

Comment: Thanks it worked after adding that permission.Thanks

Comment: @PrakaashM Great! enjoy coding